# Woocommerce Product Variations Pagination not working

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, woocommerce, pagination

I have created a custom page to show Specific Product Variation in to table list.
Here is the code:

```
        <h1> PRODUCT TABLE LIST </h1>
                <table>

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total Quantity</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody class="products">
        <?php



            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), 
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'product_cat' => '', 
            'post__in' => array( 521, 695, 852, 457, 961, 188, 399, 80, 109, 182, 108, 184, 171, 206, 197 ), // 15 products
            'orderby' => 'id',
            'paged'   => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1 );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); global $product; ?>


    <?php if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) { ?>   
    <?php show_variable_products_list(); ?>
    <?php 
    }
    else {
     ?>
    <tr class="product-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>"> 
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $wp_query->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($wp_query->post->post_title ? $wp_query->post->post_title : $wp_query->post->ID); ?>">
    <td class="image">
                            <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $wp_query->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($wp_query->post->ID, 'wh_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="150px" height="150px" />'; ?>
    </td>

    <td class="title">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    </td>

    <td class="note">
        <?php wholesale_msg_note(); ?>
        <?php wholesale_letter_note(); ?>
    </td>

    <td class="price">

    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
        <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>
    </span>
        <?php echo $product->get_price() ?>
    </span>                 
    </td>

    </a>

    <td class="quantity-cs">
        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <?php echo wholesale_sc_note(); ?>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <?php echo wholesale_kw_note(); ?>
                            </tr>
        </table>

    </td>



    <td class="quantity-total">
        <?php //woocommerce_quantity_input(); //This function generates the quantity field. ?>
        <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" />
    </div>
    </td>

    <td class="button">

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    <button type="submit" class="button buy-now-btn cart-btn product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" />Add to Cart</button>

    </td>

    </form>



     <?php 
    }
     ?>




                </tr>
                </tbody>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

                </table><!--/.products-->
    <div>
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link( 'New Posts' , $wp_query->max_num_pages ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php       
    /*
      PAGINATION
    */
    if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
        ?>

        <div id="pagination">
            <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    ?>
```

Both the pagination works great for simple products but I am also using variable products to show here in this table format.
Here is the code:

```
    function show_variable_products_list(){
        global $product, $post;

        $variations = find_valid_variations();


        // Check if the special 'price_grid' meta is set, if it is, load the default template:
        if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_grid', true) ) {
            // Enqueue variation scripts
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

            // Load the template
            wc_get_template( 'woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
                    'available_variations'  => $product->get_available_variations(),
                    'attributes'            => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
                    'selected_attributes'   => $product->get_variation_default_attributes()
                ) );
            return;
        }

        // Cool, lets do our own template!
        ?>


                <?php
                foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
                    if( !$value['variation_is_visible'] ) continue;
                ?>
                <tr class="product-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?> variation-<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>"> 
                  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">  
                    <td class="image">
                        <?php echo '<img src="'.$value['image_src'].'" alt="'.$product->get_title().'-'.$value['variation_id'].'" width="150px" height="150px" />'; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="title">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3><br />
                        <b><?php 
                        /*
                         - '.get_term_by().'
                        foreach($value['attributes'] as $key => $val ) {
                            $val = str_replace(array('-','_'), ' ', $val);
                            printf( '<span class="attr attr-%s">%s</span>', $key, ucwords($ival) );
                        } 
                        */

                        foreach($value['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                        $attr_name = substr($attr_name, 10);
                        $attr = get_term_by('slug', $attr_value, $attr_name);
                        $attr_value = $attr->name;
                        echo $attr_value, '  ';
                        //echo implode ('/', $attr_value );
                        //echo $attr->name;
                        //$attr_implode_name = implode(",", $value['attributes']);

                        //echo $attr_implode_name;

                        } 
                        ?></b>
                        </td>

                    <td class="note">
                        <?php wholesale_msg_note(); ?>
                        <?php wholesale_letter_note(); ?>
                    </td>   
                    <td class="price">
                        <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="keyblade">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <?php echo wholesale_sc_note(); ?>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <?php echo wholesale_kw_note(); ?>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>

                        <?php if( $value['is_in_stock'] ) { ?>


                        <td>
                            <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php
                            if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                                foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                                ?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                                <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-primary ajax_add_to_cart"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Add to cart</button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />

                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
                        <?php } ?>

                        </td>
                        </form>

                        </tr>
                <?php } ?>


        <?php
    }


    function find_valid_variations() {
        global $product;

        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        $new_variants = array();

        // Loop through all variations
        foreach( $variations as $variation ) {

            // Peruse the attributes.

            // 1. If both are explicitly set, this is a valid variation
            // 2. If one is not set, that means any, and we must 'create' the rest.

            $valid = true; // so far
            foreach( $attributes as $slug => $args ) {
                if( array_key_exists("attribute_$slug", $variation['attributes']) && !empty($variation['attributes']["attribute_$slug"]) ) {
                    // Exists

                } else {
                    // Not exists, create
                    $valid = false; // it contains 'anys'
                    // loop through all options for the 'ANY' attribute, and add each
                    foreach( explode( '|', $attributes[$slug]['value']) as $attribute ) {
                        $attribute = trim( $attribute );
                        $new_variant = $variation;
                        $new_variant['attributes']["attribute_$slug"] = $attribute;
                        $new_variants[] = $new_variant;
                        //$woocommerce->attribute_label
                    }

                }
            }

            // This contains ALL set attributes, and is itself a 'valid' variation.
            if( $valid )
                $new_variants[] = $variation;

        }

        return $new_variants;
    }           

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'show_variable_products_list', 10, 2 );
```

The problem is if the page have 2 simple product & 3 variable product with say 3 variations each then the page shows **2 + 3x3 = 11** products instead of 5.

What am I doing wrong? How can I show 5 products in each page even with variable products?

Comment: Hi, did you solved your problem? I building similar variation table and want to do a pagination. Could you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868261/woocommerce-product-variations-pagination-issue