# Woocommerce Product Variations Pagination issue

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, html-table, pagination

I made a table for single product variations and I trying to do pagination.
I'm using variable products with few custom attributes. So the issue is that pagination is not working and showing too many pages.

For example, for one product I have 15 variations on the first page and total but pagination shows 14 total page. Also if I set posts_per_page for example 2, then all variations are multiplied by 2 (duplicated) and so on.

This is my table

[image]

**Full Code in functions.php**

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart(){
    global $product, $post, $woocommerce;

    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

    $variations = find_valid_variations();

    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'price_grid', true) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );

        wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php', array(
                'available_variations'  => $product->get_available_variations(),
                'attributes'            => $product->get_variation_attributes(),
                'selected_attributes'   => $product->get_variation_default_attributes()
            ) );
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <table class="variations variations-grid" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> Date</td>
            <td> Location </td>
            <td> Price </td>
            <td> Quantity </td>
            <td> Availability </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $args = ( array(
            'post_type'     => array('product_variation'),
            'posts_per_page'=> 1,
            'post_status'   => array('private', 'publish'),
            //'post_in' => array('product'),
            'product_cat'   => '',
            'paged'   => $paged,
            'post_parent'   => get_the_ID()
            ) );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

            while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <?php
            foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
                if( !$value['variation_is_visible'] ) continue;
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="date">
                    <?php 
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($value['attributes'] as $key => $val ) {
                            if($i == 0 ) {
                                echo $val;
                            }
                        $i++;
                        } 
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td class="location">
                    <?php
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($value['attributes'] as $key => $val ) {
                            if($i !== 0) {
                                echo $val;
                            } 
                        $i++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td class="price">
                        <?php echo '<span>&pound;</span>' . $product->get_price(); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="quantity">
                    <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="stock">
                    <?php if (!$value['is_in_stock'] ) { ?>
                      <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'Places Not Available', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                 <p class="stock in-stock"><?php _e( 'Places Available', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td class="add-to-cart">
                    <form class="cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                        <?php
                        if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                            foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                            ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                            <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Add to cart</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                    </form>
                    <?php } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
    <?php
        if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
        ?>

        <div id="pagination">
            <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php
}
```

```
function find_valid_variations() {
    global $product;

    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    $new_variants = array();

    foreach( $variations as $variation ) {

        $valid = true;
        foreach( $attributes as $slug => $args ) {
            if( array_key_exists("attribute_$slug", $variation['attributes']) && !empty($variation['attributes']["attribute_$slug"]) ) {

            } else {
                $valid = false;

             foreach( explode( '|', $attributes[$slug]['value']) as $attribute ) {
                    $attribute = trim( $attribute );
                    $new_variant = $variation;
                    $new_variant['attributes']["attribute_$slug"] = $attribute;
                    $new_variants[] = $new_variant;
                }

            }
        }

        if( $valid )
            $new_variants[] = $variation;

    }

    return $new_variants;
}
```

Comment: Actually you are displaying one product by page using `posts_per_page = 1` so you need to set `posts_per_page = 12` to display 12 products per page foor example, so the number of page will decrease… see [`WP_Query` Pagination Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)

Comment: Sorry, I'm updated my question. If I set posts_per_page for example 2, then all variations are multiplied by 2 (duplicated) and so on.

Comment: But that remains to the way you have built your code. You are making that much more complicated than it should be. I hope that someone will get in your code to find out the way… But as pagination is maid by the WP_Query it's going to be complicated.

Comment: Maybe you could suggest a better way?

Comment: This is kind of broad and it should need to have all related code necessary to test and reproduce your issue (so that means all details, all needed code for custom fields… and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with one of my projects. I solved it using [**jQuery DataTables**](https://datatables.net/) plugin. Try to see if it solves yours.